# How to empty and reload a tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I am using MasterDetail template to create a SQL db, and then add and update records.  I add new records on the Detail view and then return to see them on the Master.  Because I am adding new records on the Detail view, I need to reload the array when I return to Master.  I have declared e.g. `_objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

The first add goes ok and I return to the master and there is the record.  I had read the sql table and loaded it into `_objects`.  HOWEVER, If I segue back to the Detail and then return to the Master, I now have the same record duplicated.  So, what is happening is that the array still has the record from the first time and when I read the SQL, I add the same record a second time.

So I tried to use `[_objects removeAllObjects];` thinking that this would set `_objects` back to its original state of being empty and ready for reloading from the sql table.  However, this caused the following statement to fail:

`[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

This makes me think that my assumption above is not correct.  I then tried to reset the `_object.count=0;`  which caused its own syntax error because `setobject` is not available.   I also tried  `[self.tableView reloadData];` to no avail.  Should `reloadData` somehow reference `_objects`??

Comment: I will write an answer shortly, but first, please post your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and wherever you "reload" the array (`viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` etc). Need to see what your logic is for what happens when navigating back to the master view.

Comment: See my answer below. Still, post the code you use to "reload" the array and "reload" the table. My answer is a workaround for using properties

Comment: `reloadData` fires your datasource methods, mainly `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Where and how do you modify the `_objects` (really a dumb name. How are your int's today?) array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this. One of the quickest is to use the `NSNotificationCenter` and the `NSNotification` class.

In your masterViewController, in the `viewDidLoad` method -

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) name:@"RecordEntryNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Also, add this method:

```
-(void)reloadTable {
    //This is where you should put your table updating code
    //if you need to reload the array here, do it
    //ie...
    [_objects removeAllObjects];
    [self refreshDataSource]; //whatever method to add records to the array
    //then call this:
    [self.tableView reloadData];        
}
```

In your detailView, inside the method you "create records" -

```
//create records method...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"RecordEntryNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: I am working on your response.  However, could use a little more guidance.  I did exactly (hopefully) as you suggested, but to no avail.  In Master, I am using viewWillAppear method to read the SQL and load _objects.    I put the reloadData command in there right after I test to see if _object exists.   In Detail, I am using my own prepareForSQLUpdate method which is called when the update button is clicked.  I am not using your reloadTable method because of using viewWillAppear.  How does this affect your answer?  thanks again.

Comment: Should the reloadData command go before or after the loop that reads the SQL and loads _object?

Comment: reloadData needs to go at the very end. Please post your code in `viewWillAppear` and I can tailor the response. I also want to make sure you understand what it does and WHY it works

Comment: JUSTIN -- thanks so much.  All I needed to do was to combine the removeAllObjects followed by the reloadData.

Comment: I want to make sure you understand what is going on and why it works, if you post your viewDidLoad code I can help. Otherwise mark my answer as accepted :-)